# How to fix "There is already an object named '@cloneDbName' in the database."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I separate the SQL query below according to 'GO's and run it, I get the following error:

> There is already an object named '@cloneDbName' in the database.

I wonder if I'm parsing the SQL command statement wrong?

```
private readonly string _cloneCodeCollection = @"
            

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO

            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO

            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@cloneDbName](
                [Id] [bigint] MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
                [CodePoolId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
                [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
                [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
             CONSTRAINT [PK_@cloneDbName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [Id] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
            GO

            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[@cloneDbName] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedOn]
            GO

            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[@cloneDbName]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_@cloneDbName_CodePools_CodePoolId] FOREIGN KEY([CodePoolId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[CodePools] ([Id])
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            GO

            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[@cloneDbName] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_@cloneDbName_CodePools_CodePoolId]
";

foreach (var item in this._cloneCodeCollection.Split("GO"))
            {
                await this._dataAccess.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>(
                DatabaseKey.CodePool.ToString(),
                item,
                new
                {
                    cloneDbName = "CodeCollections_BB1",
                },
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: This, `[@cloneDbName]` is a literal value, its exactly what is written, its not a variable replacement. Hence the second time you run it, yes the object already exists. SQL is a static language, it doesn't allow variable replacement for key parts of your query like you are attempting to do. You need to put the actual string of the table name there instead.

Comment: It appears that you're trying to parameterise your SQL statements. That is generally a good thing but you can only do so for values, not identifiers. Think about how a C# function with parameters works. Can you use a parameter to pas in the name of a type, member or variable? No, you cannot. You can only use it to pass in a value. SQL parameters are the same.

Comment: @DaleK, it looks like the use of parameters is encapsulated in that `_dataAccess.ExecuteScalarAsync` and populated using `cloneDbName = "CodeCollections_BB1"`.

Comment: Query parameters aren't string replacement placeholders. Just like *function parameters* in C#,  they are used to pass data, not table or column names. Databases never execute a SQL script as-is, they compile it into an execution plan that specifies the tables, indexes, scanning and join strategies to use. Query parameters are passed as parameters to the final execution plan.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? There may be a better way to do it, probably *not* involving extra tables at all. Perhaps all you need is a discriminator column in the table and possibly better indexes. If you have a lot of data that you need to move around (hundreds of thousands or millions), you can use table partitions which are available in all SQL Server versions and editions

Comment: Or you may not need a table at all. A SEQUENCE object can be used to generate incrementing values. What does `BB1` represent?

Comment: I understand thank you . Before it was executed, I changed the `@cloneDbName` in the string with the random table using the replace method. `var sqlQuery = this._cloneCodeCollection.Replace("@cloneDbName", $"{cloneCodeCollectionDbName}");`

Answer (score -3):

Yes, slightly!

You see the world that @cloneDbName exists in is not the same world as the one it is being defined in. You need to pass that variable into your command variable. Something like this:-

```
private readonly string _cloneCodeCollection = @"
        

        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO

        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + @cloneDbName + "](
            [Id] [bigint] MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
            [CodePoolId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
            [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
            [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_@cloneDbName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[" + @cloneDbName + "] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedOn]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[" + @cloneDbName + "]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
        [FK_" + @cloneDbName + "_CodePools_CodePoolId] FOREIGN KEY([CodePoolId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[CodePools] ([Id])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[" + @cloneDbName + "] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_" + 
        @cloneDbName" +_CodePools_CodePoolId]";

        foreach (var item in this._cloneCodeCollection.Split("GO"))
        {
            await this._dataAccess.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>(
            DatabaseKey.CodePool.ToString(),
            item,
            new
            {
                cloneDbName = "CodeCollections_BB1",
            },
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Thats not correct, the variable exists, but you can't use it in statements like that. In fact it doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: `[" + @cloneDbName + "]` isn't safe from injection either. Depending on the source of the value of `@cloneDbName`, this could be (very) dangerous.

Comment: cloneDBName is not defined in the SQL. I assume that the variable is coming from the FOREACH statement cloneDbName prepended somehow with the @ (I'm not a C# person). Not withstanding the c# code, the only way to get that cloneDbName populated is to pass it in, effectively making it dynamic SQL.  As with all Dynamic SQL there is a risk of injection which needs to be managed.